# Head element's going inside body

Tags: html, google-chrome

The code is....

```
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/style.css">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <title>Videos - Pranked Bros</title>
     <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/logo-7.png">

  </head>
  <body>
      <!-- other codes -->
  </body>
```

in the browser it's like:
[image: code not working]

So the code inside head tags goes inside the body tag. In this case, what should I do?

Comment: Can you please post your whole html file?

Comment: It's too large.

Comment: then remove the unimportant part.

Comment: But I think the codes inside body tag is unimportant.

Comment: is there nothing else in your html file? nothing before <head>?

Comment: There was a single inverted comma after my <!doctype html> i removed it and now it worked thanks. :) just answer it and I will accept the answer

Comment: Becareful before made a question, you wouldn't always has a privilege to ask question if yours is not a good question in terms of stackoverflow rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably something wrong with the tags before the  part, maybe this is the problem.